# How to remove an element from an array in MongoDB? $pull doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongodb

I need to remove multiple elements from different objects in MongoDB but my query returns the following error: "Cannot apply pull to a non-array value". This is my query:

```
db.getCollection('mediaelements').update(
    { customer: ObjectId("...") },
    { $pull: { competitions: { $in: [ '24', '362', '361' ] } } },
    { multi: true }
)
```

And an example of the structure of an element:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "opts" : {
        "data" : {
            "playerSide" : "both",
            "playerIconPlayer" : "p92985"
        },
        "type" : "playerIcon"
    },
    "language" : null,
    "network" : "any",
    "customer" : ObjectId("..."),
    "file" : "image.png",
    "type" : "image",
    "__v" : 0,
    "ranking" : 1,
    "competitions" : [ 
        "24",
        "58", 
        "354",
        "361"
    ],
    "medias" : []
}
```

Here I would like to remove competitions "24" and "361".

Thanks for your help

Ps: It seems to work without { multi: true }: 
"Updated 1 existing record(s) in 1ms"
With { multi: true }:
"Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value"
With $pullAll:
"$pullAll requires an array argument but was given a object"

Maybe there are some 'competitions' which aren't arrays? How could I apply this to arrays only? Or any other solution is welcome.

Comment: Use `$pullAll` instead: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/

Comment: Your approach, is perfectly working in my box, I have Mongo3.4. Please check whether you are passing the correct object ID(customer object ID)

Comment: It's working for one element, if you have multiple elements it doesn't work. $pullAll doesn't work either, it returns the following error "$pullAll requires an array argument but was given a object"

Comment: It sounds like it's failing because you have documents in the collection where competitions is not an array. When pull tries to apply it to all the documents it is failing because of this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could I target only documents where competitions is an array? Or find an alternative to remove these elements?

Comment: Not sure if theres a better way but a quick test is in your query add `{ "competitions.0" : {$exists: 1} }` This checks that the field competitions is an array with at least 1 item.

Comment: Where should I add this?
`db.getCollection('mediaelements').update(
    { customer: ObjectId("...") },
    { $pull: { competitions: { $in: [ '24', '362', '361' ] } } },
    { multi: true }
)`

Comment: If I write `{ $exists: 0 }`, I find some competitions which are set to null or which are empty arrays (with 0 elements)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `{ $pull: { competitions: { $in: [...] }}}` is not a valid usage of the operator. And nor is `{ $pullAll: { competitions: { $in: [...] }}}`, if that's what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) to update many documents
2. Use [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/) to drop specific items
3. Use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) to filter out invalid ("non-array") data.

Putting it all together:

```
db.getCollection('mediaelements').updateMany(
  { customer: ObjectId("...") },
  { "competitions.0": { "$exists": true } }, 
  { $pullAll: { "competitions": [ '24', '362', '361' ] } }
)
```

Comment: Can you explain how `competitions.0` would filter out invalid data ?

Comment: @trogne, late reply but it is because you are checking the first index of an array to see if it $exists or not.